# Getting error preg_match(): Argument #2 ($subject) must be of type string, array given

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, adminlte

I am using [laravel-8](/questions/tagged/laravel-8) and I am trying to import a template. Whenever I use `{{ asset }}` in every `link rel`, I am getting the error for some reason:

> preg_match(): Argument #2 ($subject) must be of type string, array given

I've already made my login so I'm trying to use this template but I keep getting on that error.

[image]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I already fixed the problem! I didnt need to use {{asset}} for every href. for some reason i saw someone used this "<base href="{{ \URL::to('/') }}" />" and it worked.

Comment: You can answer your own question.